# If two linear transformations are equivalent, can I say something about the equivalence of their powers?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Two linear transformations $P,$$Q:$ $V\rightarrow W$are said to be equivalent if $P=XQY$ for some invertible transformations $X$ and $Y$. I've managed to show that in such a case, $X$ gives an isomorphism from $Im(Q)$ to $Im(P)$. Using this, is there any way I can deduce something about the equivalence of, say, $P^2$ and $Q^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $V=W$ (so $P^2$ and $Q^2$ well defined).

Let $P = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $Q = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right),$ these are equivalent. However, $P^2 = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $Q^2 = \left(\begin{smallmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ which aren't.

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ and $W$ are the same vector space, then you can take $X=Y^{-1}$ so $P=XQX^{-1}$ and so $P^2=(XQX^{-1})(XQX^{-1})=XQ^2X^{-1}$ so they are equivalent.

And if $V$ and $W$ are not the same, then $P^2$ and $Q^2$ are not defined.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct, equivalent $\neq $ similar?

Comment: How do you justify setting $X=Y^{-1}$? Doing so changes the question, I think.

Comment: @amd true. My guess is op wanted to ask the question under that assumption, otherwise the result is not true.